# array of overloaded functions in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, overloading

I have several overloaded functions in c++ and I would like to make an array of them, so that I can use them in a loop (in fact I want to call them randomly). Could you help ? Tutorials only show how to do arrays of function pointers with identical function arguments.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you want to do.  Can you add some pseudocode to illlustrate what you would like to be able to do?

Comment: @Oli he wants to know how to take the address of an overloaded function

Comment: //defined in a separate class:
void ff(string x);
void ff(string x, string y);
void ff(string x, int y);
void ff(string x, int y, int z);

//what I want to do
while true
  increment count
  call method that processes functions 
method that processes functions
  call ff number count % 10
  (or random - but I don't really need random right now, later)

Comment: @SethCarnegie: And seemingly, how to call one without knowing what arguments it takes.

Comment: Is it possible to build a list (like in python) based on a condition, and give it to the function as its argument ? (I am thinking of something like a variable argument list from c#

Comment: C++ does not have the ability to generate a function call from a function pointer and an argument list.

Comment: Thank you, this definitely answers my question.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, you can try functors in C++

Comment: What are the argument to your function? If they need to be suitable to be either `std::string` or `int`, can they be converted? If so, you can use function objects which take one signature and internally convert the values call whatever signature the respective function object deals with.

Comment: Since you said "overloaded functions" and "array": not possible. The only way you could possibly do this would be to create a vector/array of `std(boost)::function` objects that have the non-common parameters bound. It is neither intrinsically possible or safe to call functions of different signatures in C++ without knowing the type & number of arguments. One could make an attempt through abuses of casts, but your result would likely be: heap or stack corrupt, or hopefully, an outright crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the main problem here is that it seems that what you want requires the determination of the type and order of the function arguments in execution time and not in compilation time. What is your main goal here? execution speed? code readability or "correctness"? If you go for execution speed, then I think that there is some ugly solution. As far I understand your problem, you will decide which "overloaded function" you will call using a random choice of the index of the array. So one not necessarily safe possibility is to use functors and pass to the creator of each functor in the array pointers to the variables it will use in the future as if those variables are its arguments. But this works only if you allways will use the same variables as the arguments of the "function" calls.

Comment: Thank you everybody, my initial solution was on the same idea as the first response above, and I tried to compress and make my code more "elegant". (Of course I also want to learn as much as possible in the process too). So now I am reading about functors, thank you dashesy and rayo hauno.

Comment: I will also read on "a vector/array of std(boost)::function objects" - that seems very interesting, and I think perfect for my purpose - thank you Nathan Ernst

Answer (score 0):

Wait so you want to call a set of overloaded functions randomly?

Why not just make a quick rand function and then use a switch statement?

for example, lets say you have 3 overloaded functions:

```
srand(time(0));
int rand = rand() % 3 // Replace 3 with number of functions.

switch(rand)
{
   case 0:
      test("this is a string!");
      break;
   case 1:
      test(12, 16);
      break;
   case 2:
      test(16.2, 3, "Hello, World!");
      break;
}
```

Otherwise you will most likely have troubles due to the fact that each function in the array would be different and expect different parameters. You would need some way to determine what parameters go to which function of which you cannot do with just the address of the function.

I would say it is rather impossible to accomplish what you are trying to do unless you use a method similar to the one described above, and even then you would need to get the parameters from somewhere.

Comment: If speeds is the main goal, then this solution will be slow. For instance, suppose you have 1.000.000 functions (I know, this is really a big number xD), then you will need to test 1.000.000 cases. Using a vector of functions on the other hand, will require constant time "access" independently of the number of functions. I know that this kind of problem (using vector of functions) is awkward, but sometime ago I faced a similar problem, I don't remember exactly how it was, but the idea was to simulate a kind of "game" where each function was some kind of strategy...

Comment: @rayo hauno True it is slow but i don't really see how you could store them in a vector. Without knowing what parameters the function requires it seems impossible. Imagine you were blindfolded and had to cut the right wire or else the bomb would explode. You have 16 wires and have no clue which one is which nor their location. You have to leave it to chance to get the correct wire. C++ is bitchy, it don't know something then it tells you to bugger off. In this case it is the same, the only way you could know is by testing each one, but c++ says no.

Comment: I have posted a weird solution above... basically you can use functors whose arguments are "references" (maybe pointers) to variables that you want to use as parameters. each functor will have its own particular, fixed set of parameters until it is destroyed.